# Show node hit counts in a VIEW?

Tags: views, nodes

I have googled and found a few articles:

http://nossdutytask.com/drupal_config/step_by_step_enable_view_post_access_counter_on_drupal

Only I don't want to show the counter as a block but as a field in a VIEW. I followed the above article but when I add fields to my view I cannot find any stat or counter or anything.

Is this possible without writing a custom module or tweaking my template.php and populating this value programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable the **Statistics** module from admin/modules.

Configure what you want to track from admin/config/system/statistics

Then edit your view.  Add a **Field**.  There will be a category called **Content Statistics** that you can filter on.  Choose the stat you want, and then configure it.

[image]

The above is for Drupal 7 / Views 3.  The steps are mostly the same for Drupal 6 and Views 2 or Views 3, but the labels are a little different.

Just keep in mind that **Statistics** module can cause performance problems on busy sites.  You may also want to check out [Radioactivity](https://drupal.org/project/radioactivity), and see if that will work better for you:

> This module provides a field type which can be used as a hotness
>   metric or a regular view counter for entities and for much much more.
>   In essense, entities receiving attention (views or actions defined by
>   Rules) are heated while inactive ones slowly cool down.

Radioactivity does integrate with Views and a few places.

Comment: I have two installs of drupal and I enabled the stats on the wrong one while developing so I didn't see it under the VIEWS of the proper site...my bad thanks again :)